# ggplot - scale_x_square()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset where the x-axis is in the range 0 to 1, and the more interesting part of the data is closer to 1, so I'd like to blow up that region.

I can use `scale_x_sqrt()` to expand the area closer to zero, so I'd like that opposite of that.

Minimum example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=seq(0,1,length.out=100), y=1:100)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_line() + scale_x_sqrt()
```

Here, I'd like to use something like `scale_x_square()` instead.

Comment: `scale_x_continuous` has a `trans` argument that allows you to pass your own custom transformation function. The docs have more info.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For completeness, here's an example. Note the bit of subtlety needed involving signs. Even if your x values only range from 0 up, since ggplot expands the plot limits by default you will need the transformation to work correctly on negative values as well.

```
pow_trans <- function(n = 2){
    scales::trans_new("pow",
                      transform = function(x) sign(x) * x^n,
                      inverse = function(x) sign(x) * abs(x)^(1/n))
}
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    scale_x_continuous(trans = pow_trans(3))
```